# How can I integrate Edx with an existing django project?

Tags: python, django, edx, openedx

I have an app already running on Django, the tutorials and documentation pre-assumes the starting of a completely new instance of Django with the default Edx installation.

I am working on an application where the Django Instances serve multiple sites and the management wants to serve another site with the same app with Edx. What is the recommended Strategy to handle this?, How can I integrate a new Edx instance with an existing Django app?, is there any tutorial or documentation handling this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenEdx is a very complicated django application, it requires a medium sized server to run in a minimal configuration, and it has a big list of dependencies.

It is not practical nor easy to integrate OpenEdx with existing django applications.

If you definitely need to integrate some other application with this, then your best course of action is to install openedx ona subdomain and use a feature of OpenEdx called [marketing site](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/Alternate-site-for-marketing-links) (feature flag: ENABLE_MKTG_SITE) and use this to integrate some of the edx pages with an external website. This would not require that the other site is a django based project.